# Born in Northern Ireland, children born in Scotland, are they entitled to Irish citizenship?

Tags: united-kingdom, citizenship, ireland

I was born in Northern Ireland in 1983 and lived there until an adult when I moved to Scotland. I am a UK citizen. I understand that I am entitled to Irish citizenship. However, less clear is whether my children, born in Scotland to myself, and a Scottish lady are also entitled to Irish citizenship. All parties are British citizens by birth, and only British citizens at the moment (I haven't taken up my right to Irish citizenship yet). My parents were also born in Northern Ireland, remain resident there, but did not take up Irish citizenship.

I find the [official documentation](https://www.dfa.ie/citizenship/) confusing on this point as it refers to grandparents rather than parents. It indicates foreign birth registration would be an option, but is this the simplest route?

So my question is, are my Scottish born children entitled to Irish citizenship? If so, by what processes?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, for the children to enjoy jus sanguinus, or the right of blood, it’s better to have those entitlements before birth or as soon thereafter as possible, but I’m sure you also sense that just want to see if there is some leeway temporarily. Hope to see you and your family back in the European family!

Comment: It seems to me the very first sentence from the link answers the question very plainly: "If you or your parent were born on the island of Ireland before 2005, you are an Irish citizen."  Reading from your child's point of view, their parent (i.e. you) was born on the island of Ireland (the northern part) before 2005 (specifically in 1983).  So your children are already Irish citizens and can simply apply for an Irish passport.  Your parents are also Irish citizens as far as Irish law is concerned, whether they "took it up" or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

> If you or your parent were born on the island of Ireland before 2005,
> you are an Irish citizen. You can apply for an Irish passport without
> making an application for citizenship.

https://www.ireland.ie/en/dfa/citizenship/